# ReactiveUI.Validations and nested validation

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I would like to know if ReactiveUI.Validation supports nested validations. Eg. a parent ViewModel that is valid only when its children ViewModels are valid.

Something like this:

```
public class ParentViewModel : ReactiveValidationObject
{
    public Parent()
    {
         var child1 = new ChildViewModel();
         var child2 = new ChildViewModel();

         this.ValidationRule(child1);
         this.ValidationRule(child2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`IsValid()`](https://www.reactiveui.net/api/reactiveui.validation.extensions.validatableviewmodelextensions#ReactiveUI_Validation_Extensions_ValidatableViewModelExtensions_IsValid__1___0_) extension method to get an `IObservable<bool>` instance to get the valid state of the inner model. Use it in your "main" model at your `ValidationRule()` method with the [`ValidationRule(IObservable<bool>, string)`](https://www.reactiveui.net/api/reactiveui.validation.extensions.validatableviewmodelextensions#ReactiveUI_Validation_Extensions_ValidatableViewModelExtensions_ValidationRule__1___0_System_IObservable_System_Boolean__System_String_) overload. See the following example:

```
public class ParentViewModel : ReactiveValidationObject
{
    public Parent()
    {
         var child1 = new ChildViewModel();
         var child2 = new ChildViewModel();

         this.ValidationRule(child1.IsValid(), "the first child model is invalid");
         this.ValidationRule(child2.IsValid(), "the second child model is invalid");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, if you do not bind the `ChildViewModel` to the UI for example, would be to combine the two `ValidationContext`s:

```cs
public class ParentViewModel : ReactiveValidationObject
{
    public ParentViewModel()
    {
         var child1 = new ChildViewModel();
         var child2 = new ChildViewModel();

         ValidationContext.Add(child1.ValidationContext);
         ValidationContext.Add(child2.ValidationContext);
    }
}
```